# My hist function is not doing plots in R, what can i do?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

my My hist function is not doing plots in R, what can i do?
This is an example of the data:

```
b=c(34,34,34,5,6,9,0,10,22,23)
t=hist(b)
t
```

and the output is:

```
$breaks
[1]  0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35
$counts
[1] 2 3 0 0 2 0 3
$density
[1] 0.04 0.06 0.00 0.00 0.04 0.00 0.06
$mids
[1]  2.5  7.5 12.5 17.5 22.5 27.5 32.5
$xname
[1] "b"
$equidist
[1] TRUE
attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

What can I do? thanks.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question. When you provide code, make sure _it works_, the code you initially provided will not parse in R (expressions must be separated by semi-colons or newlines, not the commas you originally had). I also suggest putting the output in a code block, doing so helps break it out visually from your description. Feel free to roll back the edit if it isn't right for you.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. When I run the first two lines of code (`b=..` and `t=..`), my graphics window shows the histogram. If you are using RStudio, please verify that the graphics pane is not collapsed/hidden; if you are using another IDE for R, please specify it and/or reference _their_ documentation; if you are using R remotely over a tunnel (e.g., using `ssh` and a simple terminal), then you will not be able to see plots, you might find a `Rplot.pdf` file (or similar name) in your current working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General considerations

The `hist` function in your case does *exactly* what it supposed to do. This function is used mainly for it's *sideffect* i.e. *plotting the histogram* (when argument `plot` is `TRUE` which is the *default*). But the *value* function returns is a *list* with several components (`breaks`, `counts`, `density`, `mids`, `xname`, `equidist`). So when you call `t = hist(b)` you assign the *value* returned by `hist` function, to the variable `t` (btw `t` is the function in R, I wouldn't use `t` as a variable name). As a result, when you cal `t` it prints returned value, a *list* mentioned above, but *not a plot* which you probably expect to see.

### Getting your hands dirty (update)

Assuming that your objective is to *save* a histogram and plot it latter, you can use following observations:

#### Reproducible data

First we create a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(72158867)

x <- rnorm(100)
```

Here we assigned 100 random values to the variable `x`.

#### Create histogram, without plotting, assign the result to the variable

Now we are ready to create a histogram, and assign the result returned by `hist()` to the variable `h`:

```
h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
```

Here, with the argument `plot = FALSE` we tell the function to return result *without plotting*.

#### Inspect the content of `h`

The *value* returned by `hist()` is an *object*. We can dig into this object, to find how to work with it in order to achieve our *objectives*.

##### Structure of the returned object

First we can examine the *structure* of the returned object using the `str()` function:

```
str(h)

# List of 6
# $ breaks  : num [1:11] -2 -1.5 -1 -0.5 0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 ...
# $ counts  : int [1:10] 5 8 15 20 17 14 14 5 1 1
# $ density : num [1:10] 0.1 0.16 0.3 0.4 0.34 0.28 0.28 0.1 0.02 0.02
# $ mids    : num [1:10] -1.75 -1.25 -0.75 -0.25 0.25 0.75 1.25 1.75 2.25 2.75
# $ xname   : chr "x"
# $ equidist: logi TRUE
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Here we can see that the object returned by `hist()` is a list-like structure, with several elements. We can also see that the result `hist()` returned is a object of a class `histogram`.

##### Class of the returned object

Another way to identify the *class* of the object returned by `hist()` is calling a `class()` function on it.

```
class(h)

#[1] "histogram"
```

You can also call `?hist` from your console, and find the information about *returned value* for the `hist()`.

##### Methods defined on the returned object

To find out what kind of *methods* are defined on the object of class `histogram` we can use `methods()` function, as shown in example below:

```
methods(class = class(h))

# [1] lines plot 
# see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Now we know that object of class `histogram` accepts two methods `lines` and `plot`. We are not interested in first one (however I wonder what it does), but second one seems to be something we are looking for.

#### Call `plot` method on the returned object

Let's call the `plot()` function on a `histogram` object:

```
plot(h, col = 'skyblue', border = 'yellow', main = 'Histogram for SOq #72158867')
```

[image]

It works as expected!

Basically, it is what `hist()` function does when you call it:

- It creates an object of class `histogram` from your data;
- It call `plot` method on your `histogram` object;
- It invisibly returns a resulting `histogram` object.

Of course there is a shorter way to find it out. Just type `?hist` in your console, and you will find all `hist`-related information by yourself.